# Unsure why record contents aren't being removed (socket.io)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, socket.io

I'm attempting to create a chat app using socket.io. I've managed to update the rooms whenever the user adds one by means of having a record kept on the back end. However, when I use similar logic, I can't get my button clicking on the front end to remove the room and all those like it on the back end.

Here's my code for the Rooms component (where I generate the contents of my record and show each room and where I have the button and the function to remove the specific room):

```
export function Rooms() {
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.emit(EVENTS.CLIENT.ON_LOAD);
  }, []);

  const { socket, roomId, rooms } = useSockets();
  const newRoomRef = useRef<any>(null);

  function handleCreateRoom() {
    const roomName = newRoomRef.current.value;
    // if (!roomName) {
    //   return;
    // }
    if (!String(roomName).trim()) return;

    socket.emit(EVENTS.CLIENT.CREATE_ROOM, { roomName });
    newRoomRef.current.value = "";
  }

  function handleJoinRoom(key: string) {
    if (key === roomId) return;

    socket.emit(EVENTS.CLIENT.JOIN_ROOM, key);
  }

  function handleRemoveRoom(key: string) {
    socket.emit(EVENTS.CLIENT.REMOVE_ROOM, key);

    newRoomRef.current.value = "";
  }
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        
      }}
    >
      <Box
        sx={{
          
        }}
      >
        <TextField
          
        />
        <Button
          
        >
          CREATE ROOM
        </Button>
      </Box>
      <Box
        
      >
        <Box
          
        >
          {Object.keys(rooms).map((key) => {
            return (
              <Card
                
              >
                <Button
                  disabled={roomId === key}
                  onClick={() => handleJoinRoom(key)}
                  sx={{ width: "100%" }}
                >
                  {rooms[key].name}
                </Button>
                <Button
                  sx={{}}
                  onClick={() => handleRemoveRoom(rooms[key].name)}
                >
                  <HighlightOffIcon style={{ color: "red" }} />
                </Button>
              </Card>
            );
          })}
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Here's the logic on my back end to remove a room as well as add rooms (I call the add rooms event from the remove room event so I figured I'd show both):

```
let rooms: Record<string, { name: string }> = {};

socket.on(EVENTS.CLIENT.CREATE_ROOM, ({ roomName }) => {
      console.log({ roomName });

      // create a roomId
      const roomId = nanoid();

      // add a new room to the rooms object
      rooms[roomId] = {
        name: roomName,
      };

      socket.join(roomId);

      // broadcast an event saying there is a new room
      socket.broadcast.emit(EVENTS.SERVER.ROOMS, rooms);

      // emit back to the room creator with all the rooms
      socket.emit(EVENTS.SERVER.ROOMS, rooms);

      // emit event back to the room creator saying they have joined a room
      socket.emit(EVENTS.SERVER.JOINED_ROOM, roomId);
    });

    socket.on(EVENTS.CLIENT.REMOVE_ROOM, (value) => {
      let deepCopy = { ...rooms };
      Object.keys(deepCopy).map((key) => {
        if (deepCopy[key].name === value) {
          delete deepCopy[key];
        }
      });
      rooms = { ...deepCopy };
      socket.emit(EVENTS.SERVER.ROOMS, rooms);
    });
```

And in my context, I'm simply updating the rooms state which is also a record:

```
  socket.on(EVENTS.SERVER.ROOMS, (value) => {
    // console.log(value);
    setRooms(value);
  });
```

It's my first time working with socket.io, so if you have any other advice, much appreciated.

Just for clarification, adding rooms works, deleting rooms doesn't.

Comment: You never do anything with the new rooms that you send from the server

Comment: I'm settting my state with that value with the line setRooms(value).